# Run sbt scoverage commande on Scala Play

Tags: scala, jenkins, playframework, sbt

I have Play project, I am trying to publish the coverage result with scoverage plugin and sbt. Everything works locally but when I try to run the same commands with jenkins it shows following error. [image]

My Jenkins Configuration for sbt is like this:

[image]

Also the configuration of build.sbt and plugins.sbt

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the instructions from [the github repo](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage/blob/master/README.md) ?

```
sbt clean coverage test
```

and

```
sbt coverageReport
```

should do the work. It seems you are missing a camel case on `coveragereport`.

you can also have a look at the [example](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage-samples/blob/master/build.sbt) they provide

also, is it an open source project we can have a look at? Or just paste the `build.sbt` and `project/plugins.sbt` files

Comment: I posted my build.sbt and plugins.sbt. I have tried the with the camel case but according to error it's failing on the first coverage command.

Comment: @AnandChokshi weird...which scala and sbt version are you using on travis?

Comment: I am using scala play Framework 2.5. As for scala it's 2.11.7 and sbt is 2.5.0. @pedrorijo91

Comment: Sbt latest version is 0.13.8 i think...you cant have sbt 2.5.0 . Run sbt about to get the version. Also, compare with the version you have in localhost

Comment: @pedroijo91 It's the plugin version. Plugin handles installation of sbt on the jenkins server. I don't have to worry about the sbt this way. but I should check on, as you suggested. Let you know if this is the case.

Comment: @pedroijio91 I checked, local and jenkins server sbt version both are similar, it's 0.13.12.

Comment: Have you found the problem? no clue about what's happening. If you can create a minimal open source project that we can have a look maybe someone can find the problem

Comment: @pedroijo91 I didn't find it. But I found the work around, rather than using the sbt plugin I am directly using shell commands to execute test coverage. This way I will not be dependant on the plugin version.